# Show that $\omega$ is an inductive set.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\omega$ be the set of all finite ordinals, i.e. $\omega=\{0,1,2,...\}$ where $0=\emptyset$
$1=\{0\}=\{\emptyset\}$
$2=\{0,1\}=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$
etc...

A set $A$ is called an inductive set if for each $n\in A$, $n+1=n\cup\{n\}\in A$.

So the problem is, am I allowed to use proof by induction to prove that $\omega=\mathbb{N}$ is inductive?

If not, what should I do?

Comment: It is true by definition, under most normal definitions. Can you be absolutely precise: how precisely is $\omega$ defined?

Comment: do you mean $k = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N},k)$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N},k) = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} : |A| = k \}$?

Comment: The definition just says $\omega$ is the set of finite ordinals, and a finite ordinal are defined to be a set satisfying a bunch of (5) properties.

Comment: You have the right to use induction, since $\omega$ is well-ordered and all its members (but $\emptyset$) have a predecessor (by definition of finite ordinal)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need induction for this proof, granted you have some theorems under your belt.

Specifically, you want that the union of two finite sets is finite, which is generally proved using induction.

Once you have that, you can show that $n$ is a finite ordinal if and only if $n\cup\{n\}$ is a finite ordinal. That is pretty much immediate from the definition.

Now, if $n$ is finite, and $\{n\}$ is certainly finite, then $n\cup\{n\}$ is also finite. Therefore $n\cup\{n\}$ is a finite ordinal. So $n\in\omega$ if and only if $n\cup\{n\}\in\omega$ as well.

So the induction was only used to prove that $n\cup\{n\}$ is finite, assuming that $n$ is finite.

Comment: We have the sticky Q of how to define "finite ordinal" without a def'n of "finite".

Comment: There are more than a handful definitions of finiteness which do not use the finite ordinals as a backbone. It's true, in some of these definitions, in the general case you'd need some choice to get equivalence (but not with all of them!), nonetheless, for ordinals it is not needed. One easy way is to say that it is a transitive set and every non-empty subset has a minimum *and* maximum in the $\in$ relation.

Comment: I was going to say more but was interrupted by something urgent.